# Significato e uso di "ribalta" in senso figurato

Tags: word-meaning, word-usage

In questa [notizia di Euronews](https://it.euronews.com/2020/08/05/parla-la-star-dell-opposizione-a-lukashenko-svetlana-tikhanovskaya-in-esclusiva-per-eurone) ho letto (grassetto mio):

> Svetlana Tikhanovskaya è passata dalla condizione di mamma casalinga alla dimensione della candidata politica quasi definita una delle donne più potenti in Bielorussia. **Una ascesa alla ribalta elettorale** tanto rapida quanto insolita.

Sul [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/ribalta) ho letto che "ribalta" può essere usato in senso figurato in espressioni come

> *chiamare, presentarsi alla r.; venire, salire alla r.* (anche in senso fig., di persona che assuma improvvisamente un importante posto nella vita di una nazione, o che comunque acquisti a un certo momento grande notorietà, e faccia molto parlare di sé).

Anche sul [dizionario dei modi di dire Hoepli](https://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario-modi-di-dire/R/ribalta.shtml) si trovano alcuni usi figurati di "ribalta":

> **essere sotto le luci della ribalta** 
> Fig.: essere al centro dell'attenzione, come un attore illuminato dalle lampade del proscenio. Riferito a personaggi noti, a persone in vista o a chiunque accentri su di sé l'interesse generale per un motivo e un periodo qualsiasi.
>
> **sognare le luci della ribalta**
> Fig.: cercare facili successi, come un aspirante attore che al mondo del teatro chiedesse solo la notorietà.
>
> **venire alla ribalta** 
> Imporsi all'attenzione, arrivare alla notorietà, diventare un personaggio pubblico o importante soprattutto se in modo repentino e inatteso. Detto anche di episodi o avvenimenti che diventano improvvisamente di grande attualità. 
> [...] 
> Var.: salire alla ribalta

Il mio primo dubbio è sul significato della frase dell'articolo di Euronews che ho evidenziato in grassetto: vuol dire che Svetlana Tikhanovskaya ha assunto improvvisamente un ruolo importante nella campagna elettorale in Bielorussia?

Ho poi ricercato su Google e mi sono accorta che si possono trovare molti esempi di uso figurato del termine "ribalta", ma che non sempre appaiono in espressioni simili a quelle che riportano le voci citate sopra del vocabolario Treccani e  del dizionario dei modi di dire Hoepli.

Faccio alcuni esempi (grassetto mio).

[Esempio 1](https://www.gambatesanews.it/?p=35820):

> Nella sua ospitata da Bruno Vespa a Porta a Porta, prima aspra­mente criticato, ai limiti di una riedizione del famoso ‘editto bulga­ro’ e poi utilizzato come **ribalta** elettorale, il leader del Movimento 5 Stelle ha detto esattamente queste parole: [...].

[Esempio 2](https://www.diariodelweb.it/economia/articolo/?nid=20130125_278578):

> L'assemblea, già scelta come ghiotta occasione di **ribalta** elettorale prima della bufera sul Monte degli ultimi giorni, si prospetta ora quantomeno intensa e 'molto vivace' e vedrà la partecipazione del leader del Movimento 5 Stelle, Beppe Grillo, e del giornalista Oscar Giannino, 'new entry' nell'agone politico con 'Fermare il declino'.

[Esempio 3](https://www.dinamobasket.com/it/blog/la-sardegna-location-dell%E2%80%99eccellenza-sportiva-presentata-la-prada-cup):

> La scelta della Sardegna come location della tappa inaugurale delle America’s Cup World Series proietta l’isola nella più alta **ribalta** sportiva internazionale: un onore e un riconoscimento per la Regione Sardegna e tutto lo sport isolano.

[Esempio 4](https://books.google.es/books?id=zfGJCgAAQBAJ&pg=PA196&lpg=PA196&dq=%22ribalta+accademica%22&source=bl&ots=nOupLkh2jM&sig=ACfU3U2UQ4esy59T-y0pYSMNJz23GsXmmQ&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwixguiironrAhVSx4UKHVPwCH8Q6AEwDHoECAcQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22ribalta%20accademica%22&f=false):

> Dopo quasi un secolo di oblio rispetto ai contributi marshalliani, alla sua **ribalta** accademica sul finire degli anni Settanta, lo studio dei distretti industriali occupa un posto in evidenza nel dibattito italiano ed europeo sulla crescita industriale, avendo sollecitato, per le sue potenzialità di stimolare lo sviluppo economico "dal basso", l'interesse sviluppo endogeno.

[Esempio 5](https://books.google.es/books?id=jxa3DwAAQBAJ&pg=PA124&dq=%22come+ribalta%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjqm9iYsYnrAhXSz4UKHd1sANIQ6AEwA3oECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22come%20ribalta%22&f=false):

> Molte altre sarebbero iniziative artistiche da menzionare, ci si limita solo a ricordare tra quelle di particolare rilievo, la *Berlinale*, il festival internazionale del cinema di Berlino che ha assunto sempre maggiore importanza come **ribalta** di qualità, innovazione e sperimentazione.

Potreste dirmi qualcosa sugli usi di "ribalta"
in senso figurato a parte quelli riportati dal vocabolario Treccani e dal dizionario dei modi di dire Hoepli?

Comment: Il senso è quello di “grande visibilità” (ribalta) in occasione delle prossime delle elezioni.

Comment: La ribalta è un termine che si riferisce alla parte del palcoscenico  più sporgente verso il pubblico dove gli attori sono  più vicini e meglio visti dalla platea. Figurativamente la ribalta è una posizione di grande visibilità, in genere per una posizione importante.

Comment: Si potrebbe dire che la Signora Svetlana   si è trovata improvvisamente “in prima linea sul palcoscenico  della campagna elettorale.”

Comment: Capisco, @Hachi: guardando gli esempi che trovo su Google, immagino questo sia il principale uso che si fa dell'espressione. Forse altri utilizzi di questa espressione sono per esprimere una certa azione che possa far arrivare qualcuno o un partito politico a questa prima linea nella campagna  elettorale?

Comment: Per esempio, "ghiotta occasione di ribalta elettorale" vorrebbe dire che qualcuno ha visto nell'azione che si sta spiegando (la scelta di questa assemblea) un'opportunità per situarsi in prima linea nella campagna  elettorale?

Comment: L’assemblea degli azionisti del Monte Paschi era stata scelta da Grillo e Giannino  come occasione per mettersi in vista e far parlare di se in occasione delle elezioni di quel periodo.

Comment: Va bene, @Hachi: capisco. L'unico è che, in questi casi, non si tratta di qualcosa di improvviso, come spiega il Treccani. Quindi, oltre all'aggiunta dell'aggettivo "elettorale", sembra si sia fatta un'estensione nell'uso del termine. Per questa ragione non potevo capirlo del tutto bene solo con l'aiuto del dizionario.

Comment: Il senso si qualcosa di improvviso e inaspettato è relativo all’espressione ***venire alla ribalta*** - 
*Imporsi all'attenzione, arrivare alla notorietà, diventare un personaggio pubblico o importante soprattutto se in modo repentino e inatteso. Detto anche di episodi o avvenimenti che diventano improvvisamente di grande attualità.* In generale la ribalta non è indicativa di qualcosa di improvviso. https://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario-modi-di-dire/R/ribalta.shtml

Comment: Sì, @Hachi, ma il significato di questa e altre espressioni simili è l'unico che sono riuscita a trovare sui dizionari: è per questa ragione che avevo bisogno di porre questa domanda. Ho usato il Treccani perché mi sembrava più completo.

Comment: Scusa ma a questo punto non sono sicuro di aver veramente capito la tua domanda che, mi sembra,  sia relativa al fatto che la “*ribalta elettorale*” sia qualcosa di improvviso e inatteso o meno?

Comment: @Hachi: La mia domanda è semplicemente cosa significa e come si usa l'espressione "ribalta elettorale" perché con l'aiuto di quello che si trova sui dizionari non mi è chiaro (e penso lo stesso potrebbe accadere ad altre persone che non abbiano dimestichezza con l'espressione). Adesso, grazie ai tuoi commenti, credo di averlo più o meno capito, ma bisognerebbe scrivere una risposta.

Comment: Ho l'impressione che in questo caso non si tratti di una frase fatta o un'espressione idiomatica (che avrebbe un senso diverso da quello ricavabile dalle singole parole che la compongono), ma solo di un normale nome (usato in modo figurato) e di un normale aggettivo giustapposti: volendo, si potrebbe parlare anche di ribalta sportiva, ribalta accademica e così via.

Comment: Ah, OK, @DaG: allora questi usi non avrebbero a che vedere con quello che ho riportato dal Treccani né con la citazione dal dizionario dei modi di dire Hoepli fatta da Hachi? E "ribalta" in senso figurato sarebbe che cosa? Quello che ha detto Hachi nei suoi primi commenti?

Comment: Va bene, @DaG, cerco di modificare la domanda.

Comment: Sono d'accordo con tutto quello che ha spiegato @Hachi: in senso figurato la “ribalta” (spesso ma non necessariamente usata con espressione come “venire alla r.”) è appunto una situazione di grande notorietà etc.